# Issue with Vue.js Event Modifier

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've got the following scenario, when the dropdown is changed the control will update the data table.  The syntax for both:

```
<template id="ux-selector">
     <el-select v-on:change="updateTable()" v-model="option">
         <el-option v-for="option in options" :label="option.Label" :value="option.Value"></el-option>
     </el-select>
</template>
```

The syntax for the table, would be as follows:

```
<template id="ux-table">
     <el-table :data="sampleObject" height="250" highlight-current-row @current-change="handleTableSelect">
         <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name"></el-table-column>
         <el-table-column prop="address" label="Address"></el-table-column>
         <el-table-column prop="status" label="Status"></el-table-column>
     </el-table>
</template>
```

So if I manually do them separately, populated:

```
var Application = {
    data() {
      return {
        options: buildDateDropdown()
      }
    }
  };

var Ctor = Vue.extend(Application);
new Ctor().$mount('#ux-selector');
```

The code will work as intended, building my dropdown.  The issue, is when I attempt to utilize my Vue code and make use of components.

```
var dropdownComponent = Vue.component('date-dropdown', {
     el: '#application-header',
     template: 'ux-selector',
     data: { options: buildDateDropdown() },
     methods: {
         updateTable: function() {
              const month = this.option.selected.value.split('~')[0];
              const year = this.option.selected.value.split('~')[1];

              axios.get('/Home', {
                   params: {
                       Month: month,
                       Year: year
                   }
              }).then(function(response) {
                  this.$.emit('sampleObject', response);
              });
         }
     }
};

var tableComponent = Vue.component('data-table', {
     el: '#application-content',
     template: 'ux-table',
     data: { 
          sampleObject: '' // Not sure how to get emit response to here.
     }
};

var application = new Vue({
    el: '#application',
    components: dropdownComponent, tableComponent
});
```

So the issue is multi-pronged, nothing appears and how do I pass from the `.$emit` to the other component, to repopulate?  An explanation and correction to make this work would hopefully shed some light on event data being passed from component to component.

Comment: Seems odd that you're trying to use global component definitions in a local scope. Have you tried changing the `Vue.component` to `Vue.extend` or just remove the `components` field in your Vue instance?

Comment: @JustinMacArthur Well, I was hoping to make use of the reusable aspect.  But I may of misunderstood.  I'm assuming once this one problem is solved, the way the framework is supposed to be used will click.  Hopefully.

Comment: yeah if you use `Vue.component` there's no need to store it as it's attaching to the global vue processor and the tag you put in `<data-table></data-table>` will become available to any vue instance mounted.
I think when you have both the defined components and the components data value it's causing conflict

Comment: @JustinMacArthur Maybe, I currently suck at Vue.  Hopefully the book I bought and some other documentation will help fill in the gaps.

Comment: Keep at it. We were all new at tech at some point. Just read, experiment, and keep asking questions. It's how you get better.

Comment: @JustinMacArthur I thought the way I was doing it, was invoking more of a child component vs global component.

Comment: Child components are usually just regular objects that are vue parsable. you define them in the object that will be their parent. Also just checking as I've noticed, your `template: 'ux-table',` should have a # infront of `ux-table` as it's a css selector.